# Cross Validation for Logistic Regression

Tags: python-2.7

I am wondering how to use cross validation in python to improve the accuracy of my logistic regression model. The dataset being used is called 'iris'. I have already successfully used cross validation for a SVM model but I am struggling to adjust my code to do the same for the logistic regression model. Here's my code so far:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
iris = datasets.load_iris()
x_iris = iris.data
y_iris = iris.target
svc = svm.SVC(C=1, kernel='linear')
k_fold = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y_iris, n_folds=10)  
# labels, the     number of folders
#for train, test in k_fold:
#    print train, test
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(svc, x_iris, y_iris, cv=k_fold,     scoring='accuracy') 
# clf.fit() is repeatedly called inside the cross_validation.cross_val_score()
print scores
print 'average score = ', np.mean(scores)
print 'std of scores = ', np.std(scores)
```

What adjustments must I make to the code to achieve successful cross validation for my logistic regression model?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: let me know if my answer from below suits your needs, otherwise I'll try to see what exactly you want, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
lg = LogisticRegression()
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(lg, x_iris, y_iris, cv=k_fold,scoring='accuracy') 
print scores
print 'average score = ', np.mean(scores)
print 'std of scores = ', np.std(scores)
```

Creating the `LogisticRegression` with default values classifier works fine for me. The output is slightly lower than the `SVM` machine approach, `0.953333333333` vs. `0.973333333333`.

But for **parameter adjustment** you can always use `GridSearchCV` which automatically performs a cross-validation of `cv` folds (in the next example I'll use `10` as you did before) trying all possible combinations of parameters. Example:

```
from sklearn import grid_search
parameters = {
            'penalty':['l2'],
            'C':[1,10,100],
            'solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag'],
        }
GS = grid_search.GridSearchCV(lg, parameters,cv=10,verbose=10)
GS.fit(x_iris,y_iris)
print GS.best_params_ # output: {'penalty': 'l2', 'C': 100, 'solver': 'liblinear'}
print GS.best_score_ # output: 0.98
```

By doing this, creating your classifier with best params `LogisticRegression(penalty='l2',C=100,solver='liblinear')` will give you a `0.98` accuracy.

> **Gentle warning**: when performing cross validation you'd better save a portion of your data for testing purposes that has not been included in the learning process. Otherwise, one way or another your learning algorithm has seen all data and you could easily fall into overfitting.